# GWT defining minimal page width

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I have a `HeaderPanel` as root object displayed on my page. How do I define minimal width for it, so when user makes browser window width less than this value, horizontal scroll for the whole page appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming you use UiBinder since you have tagged the question with "UiBinder")

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
  xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
<ui:style>
  .widthHeaderPanel { min-width:500px; }<!-- set your minimum width here -->
</ui:style>

<g:HeaderPanel addStyleNames='{style.widthHeaderPanel}'><g:HeaderPanel>
```

You basically just have to set the css property `min-width` to the value you want to have. The above sample shows how to do it with Uibinder.

Comment: Sounds like you have somewhere set the css property `overflow` to `hidden`(Could be on your `<body>` tag) . If you change that to `auto` you should be fine.